# add custom texts(labels or annotations) which are always upright to user in view port

Tags: 3d-view

I would like to put some user defined texts(labels) besides bodies as annotations, those texts(labels) are always perpendicular to user, which means whenever I rotate or scale the object, those text's size are always the same and there orientation are always upright to the user, just like the "x,y,z" in the left bottom corner of the 3D view, see the screen shot below(pointed by red arrows).

[image]

If you use the "Ruler/Protractor" tool, you will see same kinds of texts(lables) can be added by those tools.

Any ideas about this kind of text, I need such kind of text to demonstrate the models when teaching. Thanks.

EDIT: Looks like this post https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/1606/2722 give me some ways to workaround this issue, but I definitely need a clean way.

EDIT2: Now I can correctly display a text attachment to an object in the view port. But the text is not user defined, I means I can show a matrix or a object's name, but is it possible to show a customized annotation text strings?

Answer (score 8):

## Labels in Render

An easy (but limited) way would be to parent the text labels to the camera.

- Select text label <kbd>RMB</kbd>
- Add camera to selection <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>RMB</kbd>
- Set camara to parent <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd>

[image]

After that movement of the camera or transforming the objects in the scene would no longer influence the appearance of the label.

Example rotating object and moving camera:

[image]

## Labels in Viewport

If you want to draw labels in the view port you find all you need in Adhi's [display_matrix.py](https://github.com/adhihargo/display_matrix/blob/master/display_matrix.py) script.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but the added text is still a mesh, is it possible to directly a text by some python scripts, so it will shown just like the texts generated by Ruler tool.

Comment: That's pretty nice. I just wonder if the font size can be adjustable for the script.

Comment: Thanks stacker, I just download it, but I don't know how to use this add-on, any one can help me? I can't find much document about its usage.

Comment: @ollydbg23 The add-on was intended as a demonstration of the API calls required to add text labels to the viewport. As far as I understand your question you probably want to add text as object properties and display them close to the object perhaps with an offset to the center. You load the script into the text editor, press Run Script, a new section appears in the view ports properties panel ('N').

Comment: Hi, stacker, I follow the way you suggest, and now I have a "Display Matrix" section in the view ports properties panel now, thanks.