# How can I add a description to an object

Tags: mesh, objects, meta-objects

**Question:**
How can I add a description to an object. Preferably being able to shows this on top of the object, as an overlay. And that the description can be toggled to show/hide.

**Background:**

This background info does not add extra explanation to the question being asked, but I wanted to share when the question arose. I'm modelling something to print with [FDM](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fused_deposition_modeling). I wish to print without [supports](https://www.3dhubs.com/knowledge-base/supports-3d-printing-technology-overview#fdm) if possible. On some object I have used the boolean operation on a pipe. The problem is, the printing on the top of the hole where the pipe will fit isn't printed very well. This makes the hole just a bit too tight. So I stretched the hole for the pipe very little. This you can not see easily in the model. Hence I would like to add a description on the object, stating it is adjusted for 3D FDM printing. Preferably the text shows as an overlay on the object.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [add custom texts(labels or annotations) which are always upright to user in view port](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7609/add-custom-textslabels-or-annotations-which-are-always-upright-to-user-in-view)

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15729/metadata-notes-comments-in-blend-files